# Geometric Probability

Tags: statistics

It's been a while since I have done any of these and I just forgot how to do them.
given that I have a 40% chance of drawing a red card from a pile of red and black cards.

1) what is the probability that I need to draw more than 5 cards to get a red card?

2) What is the probability that I need to draw 3 cards before I draw a red card?

For the first one I am thinking either:

1. geomcdf( 7, .6 )
2. 1 - geomcdf(7, .4)

For the second problem I am thinking:

1. 1 - geomcdf( 3, .25 )

Am I on the right track here? What else should I work with?

Equations:

```
Assume this is a geometrical setting
Assume X = the number of trials wanted
Assume p = probability of a success

(equation for geompdf( X, p ))
P(X = k) = p * (1 - p) ^ (k - 1)

geomcdf is the sum of all values -1 < X < k + 1
```

Comment: What is your formula for geomcdf?  You should explain the reasoning behind the suggested answers.  for 2, what does it mean to win?

Comment: @Ross Millikan sorry for the typo, updated with equations as well.

Comment: That is not an equation, that is an algorithm to compute it.  You should be writing a formula which will indicate where the terms come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  for 1:  you need to draw five black cards in a row.  What is the chance the first black card is black?  You say the chance doesn't change.  For 2, it sounds like you are asking for specifically three blacks and then a red.  Is that correct?  The same technique works.

Comment: thanks, that is what I was guessing I just wanted to be sure.